# Changing Column Order?

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a "type mismatch" error 13 on the line IRow =...

I am wondering how this code could be fixed?

I als

Best regards.

```
Sub MoveColumns()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim data_sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim target_Sheet As Worksheet

Worksheets.Add.Name = "Final Report"
Set data_sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("InputPrep")
Set target_Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Report")

iRow = Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Determine how many rows are in use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
iRow = Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

to

```
iRow = data_sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

`Sheets(index)` expects `index` to be a sheet name or an index number. But you are passing an object of type Worksheet. Since you're already created a reference to a sheet just use it.